# In Luftrausers, How do I complete the "Kill 30 enemies while firing nonstop" mission?

Tags: luftrausers

I'm trying to complete all the normal missions in Luftrausers, but I can't seem to complete the missions for the bomb body type. It says I must kill 30 enemies while firing nonstop. Does this mean I have to kill 30 *with* the bombs I'm dropping? I feel like I've killed thirty with my primary weapon while attempting this mission, but it always seems to say 0/30 or 3/30 at the end regardless of how many enemies I kill.

Comment: I've got the same problem, although the count does increase when killing with the main weapon, it just resets randomly. It seems as though the game sometimes think you released the firing key (although in my case, I can assure my key is kept pressed, mech keyboard and all). Either the goal isn't clear enough or there's a bug.

Comment: The problem with this mission is that it effectively means that you can't regen so you can't really get hit more than a few times (and you can't switch to the armored fuselage either). I hope there is some sort of workaround

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard, but I got it by playing the "Fist of God", which is the rauser equipped with the last unlocks: Cannon, Bomb, and Hover. I flew in one direction and periodically spun around while drifting (Hover helps with this) and fired the Cannon at the fighters on my tail. Without racking up too high a streak, the score will not increase fast enough to start causing too many battleships to appear. It seems like when using Cannon the counter for this mission does not reset.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it appears discovered that the challenge actually means for you to kill 30 enemies within a combo, using only your gun and bombs. So if you accidentally kill a plane or something buy ramming into it at a 29-combo, it will reset.

Comment: Also, the Gungine resets the challenge, so be careful of that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little too late, but the challenge means that you should kill 30 people, while your bombs *still* fly. You can fire non-stop or not - that does not matter, if you have a bomb that has not yet hit anyone. Well that's at least how I got. Personal advice: fly on high altitudes - it would take longer for bombs to land.